# How to use the content of \title{} as a reference?

Tags: cross-referencing, titles

I want to be able to reference to my document title by name. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}\label{title}
\author{me}
\maketitle

The title is: "\nameref{title}" (Here it should read "Example")

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you look up `\title` in the latex source, you'll see it's defined like this:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
```

So the title is stored in a regular macro named `\@title`.  The only problem with using that to recover the title is the `@` sign, normally not allowed in control sequences.

To get around this, alias a regular macro to `\@title`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\title{Example}
\author{me}

\makeatletter
\let\inserttitle\@title
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The title is: ``\inserttitle'' (Here it should read ``Example'')

\end{document}
```

`\label` does something a little bit different.  It saves the value of the currently active *counter* (requiring an aux file and a second pass), and you want to save the *expansion text* of a macro.  Macros are well suited for the latter, and it would be hard to overload `\label` and `\nameref` to do the former.

You'll also see that I reorganized your code.  I think it's best to put macros that do not produce output like `\title` and `\author` in the preamble rather than within the `document`.  There shouldn't be anything between `\begin{document}` and `\maketitle` because you will likely get extra spaces from blank lines.  Also, having those “metadata” declarations in the preamble, and especially right after `\documentclass{}` makes it easier to identify the file to the user editing it.

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\title{Example}
\author{me}
\makeatletter\let\Title\@title\makeatother
\begin{document}

\maketitle
The title is: "\Title" 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I love it.  Not only did we post the same solution at the same time, we made the same reorganizations!

Comment: Thanks guys... I'll go with Matthews answer because of the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`authoraftertitle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/authoraftertitle) package which makes the values of `\author{...}`, `\title{...}` and `\date{...}` available via the commands `\MyAuthor`, `\MyTitle` and `\MyDate` (although I think it's kind of overkill to have a package only for this single purpose...):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{authoraftertitle}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}
\author{me}
\maketitle

The title is: "\MyTitle" (Here it does read "Example")

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I kind of agree that this is overkill.  On the other hand, this solution comes in under the “hack” threshold (which I define to be use of `@`).

Comment: @Matthew: This "package" is 32 lines long (including comments) and is fairly similar to your 'hack'.  On the basis of any code that might be reused should go in a separate file, it seems quite reasonable to put this in a package.  So I think the "overkill" is overkill!