# Redefine \title command in custom class

Tags: documentclass-writing

I am currently writing a custom class that inherits from a standard class (article), and I would like to redefine the `\title` command, so that the end user can call it, and I would be able to get the result of that command, modify it a tiny bit, and input it to the `\title` command *of the base class*.

Actually, when writing this question, I have found a way of doing this. Here is a MWE, with the class file `Test.cls`:

```
\ProvidesClass{Test}
\LoadClass{article}

\title{\@testTitle, isn't it?}
\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\@testTitle{#1}}

\endinput
```

And the user file:

```
\documentclass{Test}

\title{A great article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

So in the end, the user chooses a title, but the results outputs an article with the modified title.

Is it the standard way of doing? How would you improve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the content of \title{} as a reference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/how-to-use-the-content-of-title-as-a-reference)

Comment: The objective of this question, how to obtain the value of the \title{} command, appears to have already been addressed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15804/how-to-use-the-content-of-title-as-a-reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2760/omitting-the-date-when-using-maketitle), you can use [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox/)'s `\patchcmd` to modify the `\maketitle` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{Test}  
\title{A great article}  
\begin{document}  
\maketitle  
\end{document}
```

Test.cls

```
\ProvidesClass{Test}  
\LoadClass{article}  
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@title}{\@title{}, isn't it?}{}{}
\endinput
```

In general, you can use `\show\somecommand` to see what the definition of `\somecommand` is, and then find the part you want to patch.